# Find underlaying normal distribution of random vectors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, bayesian

I am trying to solve a statistics-related real world problem with Python and am looking for inputs on my ideas: I have *N random vectors from a m-dimensional normal distribution*. I have no information about the means and the covariance matrix of the underlying distribution, in fact also that it is a normal distribution is only an assumption, a very plausible one though. I want to compute an *approximation of the mean vector and covariance matrix* of the distribution. The number of random vectors is in the order of magnitude of 100 to 300, the dimensionality of the normal distribution is somewhere between 2 and 5. The time for the calculation should ideally not exceed 1 minute on a standard home computer.

I am currently thinking about three approaches and am happy about all suggestions for other approaches or preferences between those three:

1. **Fitting:** Make a multi dimensional histogram of all random vectors and fit a multi dimensional normal distribution to the histogram. Problem about that approach: The covariance matrix has many entries, this could possibly be a problem for the fitting process?
2. **Invert cumulative distribution function:** Make a multi dimensional histogram as approximation of the density function of the random vectors. Then integrate this to get a multi dimensional cumulative distribution function. For one dimension, this is invertible and one could use the cum-dist function to distribute random numbers like in the original distribution. Problem: For the multi-dimensional case the cum-dist function is not invertible(?) and I don't know if this approach still works then?
3. **Bayesian:** Use Bayesian Statistics with some normal distribution as prior and update for every observation. The result should always be again a normal distribution. Problem: I think this is computationally expensive? Also, I don't want the later updates have more impact on the resulting distribution than the earlier ones.

Also, maybe there is some library which has this task already implemented? I did not find exactly this in Numpy or Scipy, maybe someone has an idea where else to look?

Comment: Have you tried the expectation-maximization algorithm? It is used to estimate parameters of a density function

Comment: @politinsa That sounds like a very useful tool for my problem! Have you every applied this yourself in python or do you have suggestions for useful libraries that have implementations of that algorithm?

Comment: Are the simple estimates described in the section [Parameter estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Parameter_estimation) of the wikipedia article on the multivariate normal distribution sufficient for your needs?  If so, you can use [`numpy.cov`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) to compute the sample covariance and `numpy.mean` to compute the mean.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes a straight forward ML estimation really seems to be the best way here, especially because I expect the distribution to be a normal distribution anyway. Thank you for your help, if you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the simple estimates described in the section [Parameter estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Parameter_estimation) of the wikipedia article on the multivariate normal distribution are sufficient for your needs, you can use [numpy.mean](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) to compute the mean and [numpy.cov](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) to compute the sample covariance matrix.